# Ошибка компиляции "possible lossy conversion from double to int "

Tags: java

Нужно отсортировать массив,но компилятор ругается,выдает ошибку

> possible lossy conversion from double to int

Какую ошибку я допускаю?

```
int[] mas = {9,6,3,8,5,2,7,4,1};

for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    mas[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
}

for (int i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(mas[i] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что результат Math.floor имеет тип double, тогда как вы пытаетесь присвоить его переменной с типом int, что является сужающим преобразованием и может привести к потере данных, о чем вам и говорит компилятор. Чтобы это вылечить, приведите результат Math.floor к int, если потеря дробной части не критична (например, число 8.142 превратится в 8).
Например так:

```
mas[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
```

Либо  измените тип элементов массива с int на double

Comment: Спасибо,помогли +

Answer (score 2):

Дело в том, что `Math.floor` [определен](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor(double)) следующим образом

```
public static double floor(double a)
              ^^^^^^
```

При попытке сохранения вещественного числа в целочисленной переменной может произойти потеря данных, о чем вам выдается предупреждение

Вам нужно явно привести результат к типу `int`, чтобы сохрнаить в целочисленной переменной.

```
mas[i] = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
```

Comment: Спасибо,помогли +